# Scraping Coursera results in 404

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, phantomjs, capybara, poltergeist

Why would the following result in a 404?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'

class CourseraScraper
  include Capybara::DSL

  def initialize
    Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist
    Capybara.run_server = false
    Capybara.app_host = "https://www.coursera.org/"


    visit '/'

    save_and_open_page
  end

end

CourseraScraper.new
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not getting a 404 until the page is saved to a file and then opened in your browser and, as a guess, is being driven by some JS being loaded from the wrong referrer or not being loaded because of the referrer.

You can see this by adding `assert_text("Take the world's best courses, online.")` to the bottom of your test - which passes just fine because poltergeist is working with the normal coursera.org page

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if there's a redirect implemented if you don't have the right referral data. When I run your code, I briefly see the site load before being taken to the 404.

If instead I visit a bad url, I don't get a 404 page at all but instead a message saying "Sorry, the class you were looking for cannot be found. Please check your URL and try again."

https://www.coursera.org/badurl

Comment: interesting observation... how do I get it to work though?